# Apply a symbology from a style to a layer in a map document using arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, symbology

I've looked at a number of sources and from what I gather, it seems like the only way I can apply a symbology is to do the following:

1. Manually create a layer file that has the symbology I want already applied.
2. Apply the symbology from the created feature layer using the [arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_Management](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/apply-symbology-from-layer.htm) function.

This is what I have in code so far to do the above:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MAP_PATH)

data_frame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    symbol_name = path_to_symbol_layer_file
    temp_layer_name = layer.name

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(
        in_features=layer.dataSource,
        out_layer=temp_layer_name,
    )

    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(
        in_layer=temp_layer_name,
        in_symbology_layer=symbol_name,
    )

    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(
        data_frame=data_frame,
        update_layer=layer,
        source_layer=arcpy.mapping.Layer(temp_layer_name),
        symbology_only=True,
    )

mxd.save()

del mxd
```

I'd prefer to keep my symbologies organized in a single `.style` file and apply each one directly, without having to create a layer file for it. Is this not possible with `arcpy`?

In other words, in *pseudo-code*, I want something like:

```
style = arcpy.Style('/path/to/foo.style')

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('/path/to/bar.mxd')

for layer in arcpy.ListLayers(mxd):
  symbology = arcpy.GetSymbology(style, "custom_symbology_%s" % layer.name)

  arcpy.ApplySymbology(layer, symbology)

mxd.Save()

del mxd
```

Comment: I think you can appy unqiue symbols from a style file using the mapping library. I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve.  See here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/styleitem-class.htm

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you may want to use the settings -> style manager menu.

Comment: Why create a temporary layer? Can't you save each style as a layer, and then use the arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_Management? I do that (not using arcpy, but import symbol tool) and it works flawlessly.

Comment: I've updated my question with some pseudo-code that roughly depicts what I'm trying to achieve. Hopefully it clarifies things.

Comment: That's right, there's no need to create the temporary layer for the symbology. I've updated my question with the code I have so far.